# Wrong encoding when retrieving get argument

Tags: django, django-2.0

I have a an url encoded with URL encoding, namely : `/filebrowser/?cd=bank/fran%E7ais/essais`

The problem is that if I retrieve the argument through :

```
path = request.GET.get('relative_h', None)
```

I get :

```
/filebrowser/?cd=bank/fran�ais/essais
```

instead of:

```
/filebrowser/?cd=bank/français/essais
```

or :

```
/filebrowser/?cd=bank/fran%E7ais/essais
```

Yet, %E7 does correspond to 'ç', as you can see [there](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php).

And since the %E7 is decoded with the replacement character, I can't even use urllib.parse.unquote to get my 'ç' back...

Is there a way to get the raw argument or the correctly decoded string?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I had a look at the page you linked, and `%E7` does correspond to 'ç' on the link you provided

Comment: When you say you "get" that result, how do you know? How are you outputting that? Are you sure the issue is not just in the output method itself?

Comment: @AdamJaamour That's what I said.

Comment: @Daniel Using print(). I noticed that the code from %08 to %7E are correctly decoded by django, but not those after.

Comment: my bad @FPSedin I misread xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the request encoding to `latin-1` before accessing the parameter returned the correctly decoded string for me, when running your example locally.

```
request.encoding = 'latin-1'
path = request.GET.get('relative_h', None)
```

However, I'm not able to tell you why that would be, since I would have assumed that the default encoding of `utf-8` would have handled that particular character.

Comment: Yes I'm using Django 2.0. What do you get when you set the encoding?

Comment: The same replacement character, I also tried with iso-8859-1 and iso-8859-15

Comment: Interesting. Both latin-1 and iso-8859-1 seem to work for me. I wonder whether the issue is at the app server or OS level.